# Why does React render functional component and JSX element differently?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-table

When I assign a React component like this...

```js
<MaterialTable components={{ Toolbar: props => <CustomToolbar {...props} /> }} />
```

...or like this...

```js
<MaterialTable components={{ Toolbar: props => CustomToolbar(props) }} />
```

...it appears that React renders it differently than if it was assigned like this

```js
<MaterialTable components={{ Toolbar: CustomToolbar }} />
```

Instructions to reproduce it:

- Go to [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-table-toolbar-menu-issue-h3l12p?file=/App.js:1424-1461)
- Select a row from the table, then click on the button at the top right. The dropdown menu will pop-up on the top left of the page rather than near the button.
- Comment out line 56, then uncomment line 54, then repeat the previous step. Now the dropdown menu will pop-up near the button, as expected.

I believe this happens because the dropdown menu loses the reference to the button when its parent (the toolbar) is rendered.

Any idea how to overcome this?